# unable to resolve view name in spring boot mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using spring boot develope spring MVC application.

my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my Controller Class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class RootController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home()

{
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/next")
public String next()
{
    return "next";
}
}
```

Applciation Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.approot.controller"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class LimitBoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LimitBoApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

my spring `application.properties`

```
server.port =8090
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/AppBO
```

When I run this application i am getting this below error.

```
   Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 
  'dispatcherServlet'
   javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' 
   in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1350)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
   at  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
```

I have placed my `jsp` files in `LimitBO\src\main\resources\templates`, spring still couldnt find jsp files.

what I am doing wrong here ? I tried to add those jsp files in recources folder but still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `.jsp` files to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` and add `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/` to `application.properties`, and you dont need `@EnableWebMvc` in `RootController`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried as you said, but still same error. when I have created project it didnt create WEB-INF folder at all should I create manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Create Java configuration and try bellow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfigMvc extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver () {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp"); //this is location you put jsp
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

You need add dependecy when rendering tomcat by JSP.

```
    <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If configuration not working. Try bellow:

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
   spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```